# The name 'a' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

```
Console.Write("type first number: ");
try
{ 
    Double a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (System.FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("that's not a number");
}
Console.Write("operation: ");
string b = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("type second number: ");
try
{ 
    Double c = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (System.FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("that's not a number");
}
if (b == "+") 
{
    Double sum = a + c;
}
```

New to c#, why does it say the name "a" does not exist in the current context?

Comment: You're declaring 'a' outside of the code that you have here. You're then trying to declare it again in your first "try" block.

You should get rid of that declaration and instead assign the value - also, declarations are only usable within the scope they're defined in for local variables. Practically, that means that you need to declare them outside of those try blocks, as each try/catch block gets its own scope due to the `{}` defining a new scope.

Comment: Unfortunately you are not showing enough of your code to see where the variable `a` is declared in the outer scope. The variables `a` and `c` are local to their try blocks, so won't exist when you try to sum them. You should also check out `double.TryParse` for handling user input - relying on exceptions is not the way to go here.

Comment: You declare `a` inside `try`.  It's not available outside of it.  Same thing with `c`.  After you fix `a`, `c` will also have the same problem.

Comment: Move "Double a" outside the try, and just use "  a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());" inside the try

Answer (score 2):

Because the scope of the local `a` is the first try-catch block. It is created inside the block, and will "disappear" (go out of scope) when the block has finished executing.

You can fix it by declaring the `a` outside the block, so:

```
Console.Write("type first number: ");
double a;
try
{
    a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Every pair of {} opens a new scope. So since you open a new scope for each of your try-blocks, the variables a and c are only valid *within that block*.

Try this:

```
Double a = 0;
try
{
    a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); 
}
catch (System.FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("that's not a number");
}
```

(and similarily in the other places).

In this particular case, using TryParse() is usually the easier and better solution, because it does not involve exceptions:

```
Double a;
String input = Console.ReadLine();
if (!Double.TryParse(input, out a))
{
     Console.WriteLine("That was not a number...");
}
```

or even something like this (to prevent continuing anyway):

```
Double a;
do 
{
    String input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (Double.TryParse(input, out a))
    {
        break; 
    }
    Console.WriteLine("That was not a number... Try again. ");
}
```